# jQuery Ajax with self signed certificate fails in Android

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance

I am calling an HTTPS URL from Ajax present in my local HTML. It always fails even not sending request to server. But changing to HTTP works fine. I was trying in Android with self signed certificate.
Below is my code:`

```
$.ajax({
        url : internalserverip,
        type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        data : pjsonstring,
        dataType : "json",
        success : function (json) {
           alert("before setjson "+JSON.stringify(json));
            fnsetjson(json);
        },
        error : function (result) {
            localStorage.setItem("alertTitle", "Failure");
            localStorage.setItem("alertMsg", "server error");
            alert('server error'+result.responseText+'and'+result.status);
            //endloader();
            return "error";
        },
        async : false
    });
```

Comment: when application start up make a blank call to ur server in ajax..like$.ajax({
        url : "www.sdsaf.sd",
        type : "GET",
        cache : false,
        data : pjsonstring,
        success : function (json) {
          here enter ur app.
        },
        error : function (result) {
            localStorage.setItem("alertTitle", "Failure");
            localStorage.setItem("alertMsg", "server error");
            alert('server error'+result.responseText+'and'+result.status);
            //endloader();
            return "error";
        },
        async : false
    });